# Google Sheets ImportXml() imported content can not be parsed

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I'm trying to import data from an XML file online, though it's not working correctly.

The formula I'm using is this:

```
=IMPORTXML(https://mobileapp01.graincorp.com.au/prices?site=8440&commodity=1002000, //*[@id="collapsible86"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2])
```

And it is returning an error saying

> Imported XML content can not be parsed.

Have I done something wrong, or will it simply not work with that XML document?

Thanks

Comment: There is no tag labeled collapsible86 - which field are you trying to pull in?

Comment: I used Chrome to find and copy the xpath of a value far down in the document. It seems to grab the HTML behind the XML, which I'm not sure is right?

Comment: Can you add the original url because the xml doc your showing is not where it started.  I need to see the html page to understand what piece you want to import

Comment: The actual page is a page where you choose various options and it displays the data in that XML in a table form. I just used the network tab in chromes developer part to get the URL of the XML it loads for the data. Did you need that page or do you mean something else?

Comment: I understand how you got it - but I still need to see the html page where you make the choices - i do this all the time with sheets - I know I have the answer but I need to look at how the original source is loaded

Comment: Ahh yep, thanks for this. The site is http://graincorp.com.au/pricing/live-prices?no-intro

Comment: OK - which choices are important to you and which items of data are you trying to get? that whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what is happening - despite the fact that that endpoint is visually incredibly formatted as an xml - it turns out its actually json.

In your sheet, go to the menu and choose `Tools` and then `script editor` and paste the code I added down below into a blank script. ( delete the couple of lines it comes by default before pasting)

After you save the script - just type in `=IMPORTJSON("https://mobileapp01.graincorp.com.au/prices?site=8440&commodity=1002000")`

or `=IMPORTJSON(A1)` depending on whether or not its just a reference which also works... and voila - problem solved :)

[image]

```
/*====================================================================================================================================*
      ImportJSON by Trevor Lohrbeer (@FastFedora)
      ====================================================================================================================================
      Version:      1.1
      Project Page: http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json
      Copyright:    (c) 2012 by Trevor Lohrbeer
      License:      GNU General Public License, version 3 (GPL-3.0) 
                    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      A library for importing JSON feeds into Google spreadsheets. Functions include:
         ImportJSON            For use by end users to import a JSON feed from a URL 
         ImportJSONAdvanced    For use by script developers to easily extend the functionality of this library
      Future enhancements may include:
       - Support for a real XPath like syntax similar to ImportXML for the query parameter
       - Support for OAuth authenticated APIs
      Or feel free to write these and add on to the library yourself!
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Changelog:

      1.1    Added support for the noHeaders option
      1.0    Initial release
     *====================================================================================================================================*/
    /**
     * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
     * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
     * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
     * 
     * By default, data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
     *
     *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
     *      of the rows representing their parent elements.
     *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
     *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
     *
     * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
     *
     *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
     *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
     *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
     *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
     *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
     *
     * For example:
     *
     *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content",
     *               "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
     * 
     * @param {url} the URL to a public JSON feed
     * @param {query} a comma-separated lists of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
     * @param {options} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
     *
     * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
     **/
    function ImportJSON(url, query, options) {
      return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
    }

    /**
     * An advanced version of ImportJSON designed to be easily extended by a script. This version cannot be called from within a 
     * spreadsheet.
     *
     * Imports a JSON feed and returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. The JSON feed is flattened to create 
     * a two-dimensional array. The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to that data in 
     * the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data. 
     *
     * Use the include and transformation functions to determine what to include in the import and how to transform the data after it is
     * imported. 
     *
     * For example:
     *
     *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", 
     *               "/feed/entry",
     *                function (query, path) { return path.indexOf(query) == 0; },
     *                function (data, row, column) { data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 100); } )
     *
     * In this example, the import function checks to see if the path to the data being imported starts with the query. The transform 
     * function takes the data and truncates it. For more robust versions of these functions, see the internal code of this library.
     *
     * @param {url}           the URL to a public JSON feed
     * @param {query}         the query passed to the include function
     * @param {options}       a comma-separated list of options that may alter processing of the data
     * @param {includeFunc}   a function with the signature func(query, path, options) that returns true if the data element at the given path
     *                        should be included or false otherwise. 
     * @param {transformFunc} a function with the signature func(data, row, column, options) where data is a 2-dimensional array of the data 
     *                        and row & column are the current row and column being processed. Any return value is ignored. Note that row 0 
     *                        contains the headers for the data, so test for row==0 to process headers only.
     *
     * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
     **/
    function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
      var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

      return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
    }

    /** 
     * Encodes the given value to use within a URL.
     *
     * @param {value} the value to be encoded
     * 
     * @return the value encoded using URL percent-encoding
     */
    function URLEncode(value) {
      return encodeURIComponent(value.toString());  
    }

    /** 
     * Parses a JSON object and returns a two-dimensional array containing the data of that object.
     */
    function parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
      var headers = new Array();
      var data    = new Array();

      if (query && !Array.isArray(query) && query.toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
        query = query.toString().split(",");
      }

      if (options) {
        options = options.toString().split(",");
      }

      parseData_(headers, data, "", 1, object, query, options, includeFunc);
      parseHeaders_(headers, data);
      transformData_(data, options, transformFunc);

      return hasOption_(options, "noHeaders") ? (data.length > 1 ? data.slice(1) : new Array()) : data;
    }

    /** 
     * Parses the data contained within the given value and inserts it into the data two-dimensional array starting at the rowIndex. 
     * If the data is to be inserted into a new column, a new header is added to the headers array. The value can be an object, 
     * array or scalar value.
     *
     * If the value is an object, it's properties are iterated through and passed back into this function with the name of each 
     * property extending the path. For instance, if the object contains the property "entry" and the path passed in was "/feed",
     * this function is called with the value of the entry property and the path "/feed/entry".
     *
     * If the value is an array containing other arrays or objects, each element in the array is passed into this function with 
     * the rowIndex incremeneted for each element.
     *
     * If the value is an array containing only scalar values, those values are joined together and inserted into the data array as 
     * a single value.
     *
     * If the value is a scalar, the value is inserted directly into the data array.
     */
    function parseData_(headers, data, path, rowIndex, value, query, options, includeFunc) {
      var dataInserted = false;

      if (isObject_(value)) {
        for (key in value) {
          if (parseData_(headers, data, path + "/" + key, rowIndex, value[key], query, options, includeFunc)) {
            dataInserted = true; 
          }
        }
      } else if (Array.isArray(value) && isObjectArray_(value)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
          if (parseData_(headers, data, path, rowIndex, value[i], query, options, includeFunc)) {
            dataInserted = true;
            rowIndex++;
          }
        }
      } else if (!includeFunc || includeFunc(query, path, options)) {
        // Handle arrays containing only scalar values
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
          value = value.join(); 
        }

        // Insert new row if one doesn't already exist
        if (!data[rowIndex]) {
          data[rowIndex] = new Array();
        }

        // Add a new header if one doesn't exist
        if (!headers[path] && headers[path] != 0) {
          headers[path] = Object.keys(headers).length;
        }

        // Insert the data
        data[rowIndex][headers[path]] = value;
        dataInserted = true;
      }

      return dataInserted;
    }

    /** 
     * Parses the headers array and inserts it into the first row of the data array.
     */
    function parseHeaders_(headers, data) {
      data[0] = new Array();

      for (key in headers) {
        data[0][headers[key]] = key;
      }
    }

    /** 
     * Applies the transform function for each element in the data array, going through each column of each row.
     */
    function transformData_(data, options, transformFunc) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
          transformFunc(data, i, j, options);
        }
      }
    }

    /** 
     * Returns true if the given test value is an object; false otherwise.
     */
    function isObject_(test) {
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(test) === '[object Object]';
    }

    /** 
     * Returns true if the given test value is an array containing at least one object; false otherwise.
     */
    function isObjectArray_(test) {
      for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (isObject_(test[i])) {
          return true; 
        }
      }  

      return false;
    }

    /** 
     * Returns true if the given query applies to the given path. 
     */
    function includeXPath_(query, path, options) {
      if (!query) {
        return true; 
      } else if (Array.isArray(query)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
          if (applyXPathRule_(query[i], path, options)) {
            return true; 
          }
        }  
      } else {
        return applyXPathRule_(query, path, options);
      }

      return false; 
    };

    /** 
     * Returns true if the rule applies to the given path. 
     */
    function applyXPathRule_(rule, path, options) {
      return path.indexOf(rule) == 0; 
    }

    /** 
     * By default, this function transforms the value at the given row & column so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
     *
     *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
     *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
     *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
     *   - Values in row 0 (headers) have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title 
    *      case. 
     *
     * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
     *
     *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
     *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
     *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
     *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
     */
    function defaultTransform_(data, row, column, options) {
      if (!data[row][column]) {
        if (row < 2 || hasOption_(options, "noInherit")) {
          data[row][column] = "";
        } else {
          data[row][column] = data[row-1][column];
        }
      } 

      if (!hasOption_(options, "rawHeaders") && row == 0) {
        if (column == 0 && data[row].length > 1) {
          removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row);  
        }

        data[row][column] = toTitleCase_(data[row][column].toString().replace(/[\/\_]/g, " "));
      }

      if (!hasOption_(options, "noTruncate") && data[row][column]) {
        data[row][column] = data[row][column].toString().substr(0, 256);
      }

      if (hasOption_(options, "debugLocation")) {
        data[row][column] = "[" + row + "," + column + "]" + data[row][column];
      }
    }

    /** 
     * If all the values in the given row share the same prefix, remove that prefix.
     */
    function removeCommonPrefixes_(data, row) {
      var matchIndex = data[row][0].length;

      for (var i = 1; i < data[row].length; i++) {
        matchIndex = findEqualityEndpoint_(data[row][i-1], data[row][i], matchIndex);

        if (matchIndex == 0) {
          return;
        }
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < data[row].length; i++) {
        data[row][i] = data[row][i].substring(matchIndex, data[row][i].length);
      }
    }

    /** 
     * Locates the index where the two strings values stop being equal, stopping automatically at the stopAt index.
     */
    function findEqualityEndpoint_(string1, string2, stopAt) {
      if (!string1 || !string2) {
        return -1; 
      }

      var maxEndpoint = Math.min(stopAt, string1.length, string2.length);

      for (var i = 0; i < maxEndpoint; i++) {
        if (string1.charAt(i) != string2.charAt(i)) {
          return i;
        }
      }

      return maxEndpoint;
    }


    /** 
     * Converts the text to title case.
     */
    function toTitleCase_(text) {
      if (text == null) {
        return null;
      }

      return text.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(word) { return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
    }

    /** 
     * Returns true if the given set of options contains the given option.
     */
    function hasOption_(options, option) {
      return options && options.indexOf(option) >= 0;
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaicW.png
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more quick question, is there a way I can filter out only certain points of data in the XML/JSON and sort them into my own table layout. Like to select the name of a buyer, then their price and place them next to each other in a table?

Comment: You can use a combination of either the Query function, or the filter function to help do that - also if you get a chance can you please accept the answer if it helped?

Comment: To analyze many rows, where do you suggest adding `Utilities.sleep(1000)` into the script?