# Google Sheets "Imported Xml content can not be parsed" when importing data via Skyscanner

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I've been struggling with importing XML into Google Sheets where in most instances this is working fine. I've tried externally validating the XML and also trying to isolate the problem before coming up with two potential issues:

1. Google Sheets cannot support the length of the XML
2. Google Sheets finds an issue with the header of the XML

Any support would be very much appreciated. Spent hours on this when I'm sure the solution is incredibly simple. Many thanks.

XML used is here: https://pastebin.com/dRsTVzEg

API call used is: http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/NZ/NZD/en-GB/NZ/AU/2017-11/2017-12?apiKey={KEY}

Comment: How are you importing the XML? If you can include any relevant code or formula you have tried, that would be useful.

Comment: Using Google Sheets importxml function:

=importxml("http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/browsedates/v1.0/NZ/NZD/en-GB/AKL/SYD/2017-11/2017-12?apiKey={KEY}","/*")

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755701/google-sheets-importxml-imported-content-can-not-be-parsed